# Banach spaces involving time

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let's suppoe $u\in L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ with $u'\in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$. We know that $$u\in C([0,T];L^2(\Omega))$$.
In this result can the set $\Omega$ be the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$ or we need some regularity and boundedness assumptions on it?